# Express-session not saving

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, express-session

I'm now to nodejs and have been trying to find a solution for this problem but all of the solutions haven't been working.

req.session.user is always return undefined. it sets if I set it within a function but as soon as it exits the function it becomes undefined again. It works find from app.get/post but not when using a router

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('dotenv').config();
const app = express();
const dbo = require('./database');

app.use(cors());

const sessionMiddleware = session({
    secret: "ei_13495781kam",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: false,
        maxAge: 6000
    }
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(sessionMiddleware);

const userRoute = require('./routes/user-route');

app.use('/user', sessionMiddleware, userRoute);

app.route('/').get((req, res) => {
    req.session.user = {
        loggedIn: false,
        id: ''
    };
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('App is running on port ' + port);
    dbo.connectToServer((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
})
```

user-route.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const dbo = require('../database');
const session = require('express-session')
const {response} = require("express");

const objectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

router.route('/register').post((req, res) => {
    console.log('Hello World');
    if(typeof req.session.user === 'undefined' || !req.session.user.loggedIn) {
        let db_connection = dbo.getDb();

        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
            .then((hashedPswd) => {
                req.body.password = hashedPswd
                db_connection.collection('users').insertOne(req.body, (err, response) => {
                    if(err) throw err;
                    req.session.user = {
                        loggedIn: true,
                        id: response.insertedId
                    };
                    res.json({loggedIn: true});
                })
            })
    }
})

router.route('/session').get((req, res) => {
    if(typeof req.session.user === 'undefined') {
        req.session.user = {
            loggedIn: false,
            id: ''
        }
        res.json({sessionValid: false})
    } else {
        res.json({sessionValid: req.session.user.loggedIn})
    }
});

router.route('/login').post((req, res) => {
    let db_connection = dbo.getDb();
    const searchQuery = {
        username: req.body.username
    };

    db_connection.collection('users').findOne(searchQuery, (err, response) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(response) {
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, response.password, (err, pResponse) => {
                if(pResponse) {
                    req.session.user = {
                        loggedIn: true,
                        id: objectId(response._id),
                    }
                    req.session.save();
                    console.log("1 " + JSON.stringify(req.session.user));
                    res.json({loggedIn: true});
                } else {
                    res.json({loggedIn: false});
                }
            })
        }


    })

    console.log("2 " + req.session.user);
})

module.exports = router;
```

```
I've tried setting it if it's undefined also tried saving it manually or passing the middle ware into the app.use(/route/)
```

Comment: You have literally no error handling in the request handlers you show - thus you woulndn't even know if you were getting an error somewhere.  EVERY error path should send a response of some type and log the error on the server.  If you don't send any response, then the client just sits there waiting for a long time waiting for the response to come back.  Either client or server will eventually time things out, but in the meantime, it can really mess things up.

Comment: The server us responsed to the client fine it's just that the session isn't being set

Comment: I'm just pointing out all the missing error handling.  This is really poorly written code.  Perhaps not the problem you're asking about, but a whole bunch of other problems just waiting to happen.  EVERY code path and EVERY error must still send a response to your request.  And `throw err` inside an asynchronous callback should never be used because the exception doesn't go anywhere and can't be caught.

Comment: I'm just following tutorials so it must not be to bad if places like mongoDB are using this.....

Comment: Lots of examples are lazy and use `if(err) throw err;`.  It's wrong when used inside a plain asynchronous callback.  You shouldn't be coding that way.  I don't know why you're trying to defend having no error handling code.

Comment: Why are you running the `sessionMiddleware` twice in `app.use(sessionMiddleware);` and in `app.use('/user', sessionMiddleware, userRoute);`?

Answer (score 0):

> maxAge: 6000

Your cookie has a maxAge of 6 seconds... are you sure you made a request within six seconds of the server being started and still produced an error?